# C++ memcpy not copying as expected

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

```
    BYTE* uMemory;
    std::string data = "00 00 00 2D 01 00 B0 F9 1E 00"
    data.erase(remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), isspace), data.end());

    int address = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i += 2)
    {
        std::string data_1 = data.substr(i, 2);
        int num2 = std::stoi(data_1, 0, 16);
        memcpy(&uMemory + address, &num2, 2);
        address++;
    }
```

I'm trying to copy this into memory (2E 01 00 00 00 2D 01 00 B0 F9 1E 00) for uMemory but I don't understand the logic of it.

No matter the amount of bytes I want it to copy it always ends up like this in memory:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 2D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B0 00 00 00 F9 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00
```

Comment: Because `uMemory` is uninitialized. Is this intentional? Also `&uMemory` is the address of the local variable `uMemory`.

Comment: You do not need `memcpy()` here, just `uMemory[address++] = num2;` should work, but you need to initialize `uMmemory` properly.

Comment: This is a rather, um, inefficient way to decode hex data.

Comment: uMemory[address++] = num2; works initially but then it gets messed up in memory. How do I properly initialize it..because everything I tried prevents for the right values to be copied.

Comment: I had it this way because the string is taken from user input so it's not always "00 00 00 2D 01 00 B0 F9 1E 00"

Answer (score 0):

Your *immediate* problem here is that `uMemory` is a pointer, and in the line

`memcpy(&uMemory + address, &num2, 2);`

you are forming a *pointer to a pointer*.  `&uMemory` has type `BYTE**`, so when you do pointer arithmetic you're moving over one pointer-width each time, which is apparently 4 bytes on your platform judging by your output.

You're also clobbering a random section of memory of when you write here, likely the memory holding the `data` object itself (since that's what's declared immediately after the pointer.)

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. I would love some alternatives for better coding practices if possible.

```
    std::atomic<BYTE> uMemory[256];
    int address = 0;
    std::vector<BYTE> array;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i += 2)
    {
        std::string data_1 = data.substr(i, 2);
        DWORD num2 = std::stoi(data_1, 0, 16);
        array.push_back(num2);
    }

    std::copy(std::begin(array), std::end(array), std::begin(uMemory));
```

The only thing I'm not understanding is that I have to have std::atomic in order for the memory to not become random. Is there a different way of doing this?